# Python "problem": simple code, incorrect calculation occurs (task with codewars about counting team points) - why & where is a mistake?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, zip, compare

Solving a task ("kata") from codewars.
Сoncise and simplified description based on how I solved the problem:

> Given two lists that contains results of the game for two teams `x`
> and `y` (10 matches always).
>
> For example:
>
> - `x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]`
> - `y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4]`
>
> Points are awarded for each match as follows:
>
> - if x > y: 3 points (win)
> - if x < y: 0 points (loss)
> - if x = y: 1 point (tie)
>
> Write a function that returns the number of points team (x) got in the
> championship by the rules given above.

I wrote the code in two ways.

The first one (using the zip function) - **worked**.
The second (using *for loop*) - **no.** (simple comparing operation does not work properly and I can's figured why!). The code is very simple (see below, but the calculation is not happening correctly!).

I.e. `sum_x[4] == 2` and `sum_y[4] == 1` and **result should be equal '3'** (x > y => 3), **but it get '1' - WHY?!**

There is the code for 2 ways of how task was solved:

**1 (worked):**

```
sum_x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
sum_y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4]
    
def sum_xy():
    x = []

    for k, l in zip(sum_x, sum_y):
        if k > l:
            x.append(3)
        elif k < l:
            x.append(0)
        else:
            x.append(1)
                
    
    return x, sum(x)
```

**OUTPUT**: `([3, 3, 3, 3, **3**, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 15)`

**2 (does't work!):**

```
sum_x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
sum_y = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4]
    
def sum_xy():
    x = []

    for k in sum_x:
        for l in sum_y:
            if k > l:
                x.append(3)
            elif k < l:
                x.append(0)
            else:
                x.append(1)


        return x, sum(x)
```

**OUTPUT**: `([3, 3, 3, 3, **1**, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 13)`

Why there is `1` when it should be `3`? - That's my question.

Comment: Before your `if` statement, try `print(k, l)`. That should demonstrate the difference between what's happening in your two loops. Also, you probably intended to have the `return` statement in (2) indented one stop to the left. Fixing that would have made the difference in the two outputs much more dramatic.

Comment: "More dramatic" it really is: one stop to the left make 100 elements overall and now (thanks to Barmar) I know why. Thanks for the great advice.

Answer (score 1):

Version 2 is only comparing the first element of `sum_x` to each element of `sum_y`. It then returns the result at the end of the first iteration of the outer loop. So you get `1` because `sum_x[0] == sum_y[4]`.

If you moved the `return` statement to the end, it would still be wrong because they it would compare every element of the two lists, not just the corresponding elements. The result would be 100 elements long instead of just 8.

If you don't want to use `zip()`, you need to use the indexes to get the corresponding element.

```
def sum_xy():
    x = []

    for i, k in enumerate(sum_x):
        l = sum_y[i]
        if k > l:
            x.append(3)
        elif k < l:
            x.append(0)
        else:
            x.append(1)

    return x, sum(x)
```

Comment: Got it! I "print"-ed "i, k, l" out and now understand the "inner kitchen" more deeply. Thank you for helping figuring it all out.